# Does there exists a StockFish .Net library wrapper

Tags: chess

For the record, I checked out PortFish, which was interesting, but being a port, and from 2012, I would rather use library functions wrapping the actual engine.

If there are none, have anybody here ever wrapped it themselves? Preferably such that it works on both Linux and Windows ...

I am considering creating a GUI frontend for it for a webapp, created with [Phosphorus Five](https://github.com/polterguy/phosphorusfive)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it yourself in a very simple way... Call Stockfish by system command.

Comment: Can you expound? I know I can run an exe with `Process`, but I haven't figured out how to send commands and read output.

Comment: Running commands that complete right away are well-documented. Running commands that continue to run in the background and that we want to constantly interact with is harder to find. In the end, the only solution I came up with was using eventing with asynchronous calls, but the result is far from simple.